# i got this error while connecting smart contract and frontend application

Tags: solidity, blockchain

```
const hre = require ("hardhat");

async function  main() {
  const NFTMarketplace = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarketplace");
  const nftmarketplace = await NFTMarketplace.deploy();

  await nftmarketplace.deployed();

  console.log(` deployed contract Address ${nftmarketplace.address}`);
  }

  main().catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error);
  process.exitCode =1;
})
```

[image];

Answer (score 1):

`await nftmarketplace.deployed();` doesn't work anymore in the new version, replace it with   `await nftmarketplace.waitForDeployment();`